# CRUD for 3 different entities node js /express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, crud, forum

I am a beginner in Node Js /Express and am currently trying to design a simple chess forum. I am having great difficulty creating the CRUD functions for the different entities. The 3 entities are: User, Message and Colour.
Their relationship to each other is User.OneToMany(Message) and Colour.OneToMany(Message).I use Mongoose.

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var user = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  }
});

const UserDB=  mongoose.model('user', user);
module.exports =  UserDB;
```

**message.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

var message = new Schema({
  titel: {
    type: String
  },
  message: {
    type: String
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  color: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'color'
  }
});

const MessageDB=  mongoose.model('message', message);
module.exports=MessageDB
```

**color.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

var color = new Schema({
  color: {
    type: String
  }
});
const ColorDB=mongoose.model('Color', color);

module.exports=ColorDB
```

I have implemented all the CRUD functions for the user.

**controller.js**

```
var UserDB = require('../model/user');


//CRUD for User
//(c)reate new User
exports.create=(req,res)=>{

    //validate
    if(!req.body){
        res.status(400).send({message:'Empty'});
        return;
    }
    //hash password
    //const hashedPassword= bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,salt)
    //
    //new user
    const user = new UserDB({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    //save database
    user
        .save(user)
        .then(data => {
            res.redirect('/signup')
            
            
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.status(500).send({
                
                message: err.message || "Mars Attacks !"
            })
            
        });
        
}

//(r)ead User
exports.find=(req,res)=>{
    //find by email (login)
    if (req.query.email){
        const email=req.query.email;
        const password=req.query.password;
        UserDB.findOne({email: email, password:password})
            .then(data=>{
                if(!data){
                    res.status(404).send({message: 'Not found user with email' +email})
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/forum')
                }
            })
            
            .catch(err=>{
                res.status(500).send({message: 'Error reading user with email' +email})
            })
        }
    
    //find by id
    if(req.query.id){
        const id=req.query.id;
        UserDB.findById(id)
        .then(data=>{
            if(!data){
                res.status(404).send({message: 'Not found user with id' +id})
            } else{
                res.send(data)
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            res.status(500).send({message: 'Error reading user with id' +id })
        })

    }else{
    UserDB.find()
    .then(user =>{
        res.send(user)
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || 'Ack! Ack!' })
    })
}
}

//(u)pdate User
exports.update=(req,res)=>{
    if(!req.body){
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send({message: 'Data to update can not be empty.'})
    }
    const id= req.params.id;
    UserDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,{useFindAndModify: false})
        .then(data=>{
            if(!data){
                res.status(404).send({message: `Cannot Update user with ${id}`})
            }else{
                res.send(data)
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            res.status(500).send({message: 'Laserbeam !'})
        })
    }




//(d)elete User
exports.delete=(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    UserDB.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(data=> {
            if(!data){
                res.status(404).send({message: `Cannot Delete ${id}`})
            }else{
                res.send({
                message: 'Gone!'
            })
        }
    })
        .catch(err=>{
            res.status(500).send({
                message:'Ack ! Could not delete User with id=' + id
            });
            });
        }
```

My router looks like this:

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const controller = require ('../controller/controller');

//API
route.post('/api/users',controller.create);
route.get('/api/users',controller.find);
route.put('/api/users/:id',controller.update);
route.delete('/api/users/:id',controller.delete);

module.exports=route;
```

I tried to transfer the concept of the controller to the other 2 entities (message,colour). Unfortunately in vain. What are the crud functions for the other two entities ?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to save the user ID as a session or via token. I would suggest look into [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) for more information on this one.

After you have set the session.. you can access the userID in `req.user`.

You can now easily create a CRUD like this as an example - create only

```
// route
route.post('/api/message',messageController.create);


// create controller
// post data json
// {
//  color:'color_ID'
// }
function create(req, res){
    const message = {
        titel:'this is a title',
        message:'this is a message',
        user: req.user,
        color: req.body.color
    };

    await Message.create(message);
    res.json({mesage:'Message Created'})
}
```